# ShareThis Issue

Tags: facebook, sharing, sharethis

When we share an article from our website through sharethis we get this: http://www.tothemaonline.com/athlitika/kypros/video-me-spasmena-frena-i-ael#sthash.HdfstLZK.gbpl.

When we paste the link in Facebook object debugger we get: `Curl Error : OPERATION_TIMEOUTED Operation timed out after 10004 milliseconds with 0 out of -1 bytes received`.

We check both sharethis and our website and did not found any problems.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working fine now..

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fshar.es%2FBhh9p